# Почему код идет по ветке с выводом "Не работает"?

Tags: php

Не работает и пишет "Не работает". При этом если менять ячейку, скажем, Like на nick, то всё прекрасно работает. Хоть намекните что ли...

```
<?
session_start();
include("bd.php");

if (!empty($_SESSION['email']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
    $email    = $_SESSION['email'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $result   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'", $db);
    $myrow    = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $liks     = $myrow['like'];
    if (empty($myrow['email'])) {
        exit("Пользователя не существует! Возможно он был удален.");
    }
    if (empty($myrow['id'])) {
        exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");
    }
} else {
    exit("<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php'></head><body></body></html>");
}

if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
    $like    = $liks + 1;
    $result4 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET like='$like' WHERE email='$email'", $db);
    if ($result4 == 'TRUE') {
        echo "Like! <a href='page.php?id=" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'>Моя страница</a>.<br><br>";
    } else {
        echo "Не работает! <a href='page.php?id=" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'>Моя страница</a>.<br>$like<br> $email";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: И я там делаю так, что нужно сначала извлечь кол-во лайков, потом к этому количеству прибавить 1 и обновить базу. Возможно, это делать сразу при обновлении базы? Что-то типа:

    UPDATE users SET like='+1' WHERE email='$email'

Comment: mysql_query устарел.

Comment: @Kirpich643 Заголовок вопроса должен отражать его содержание.

Comment: Пишется "моя страница",
php не помню 100лет назад было,
а что именно не работает? запрос UPDATE users SET like='$like' WHERE email='$email'",$db?

Comment: Предлагаю убить автора.  Как минимум по причине того, что он хочет, чтоб всё сделали за него

Comment: Неработоет запрос UPDATE users SET like='$like' WHERE email='$email'",$db

Comment: "mysql_query устарел." и ЧЕМ МНЕ ТОГДА ПОЛЬЗОВАТСЯ ?

Comment: @Kirpich643, MySQLi

Comment: @Kirpich643 - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHosLhPEN3k ;D

Comment: if you are Chuck Norris... http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=fvwp&v=tqv-ZzXpeAs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это что за убогость в стиле Евгения Попова?

```
if($result4 == 'TRUE'){
```

Где вы этой пошлости набрались? Делаем просто:

```
if($result4){
```

Где у вас экранирование данных? Что это за такие загадочные проверки: **empty($myrow['email'])** и **empty($myrow['id'])**? И почему бы вам в эту строку:

```
exit("<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php'></head><body></body></html>");
```

не добавить еще html-кода на пару десяток строк? А зачем использовать **mysql_fetch_array()**? Вы используете ассоциативный массив, а численный вам зачем? В нагрузку?

Answer (score 2):

```
if($result4 == 'TRUE'){
```

не правильно

```
if($result4){
```

правильно, mysql_query для запросов типа INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, и т.п. восзвращает БУЛЕВЫЙ тип TRUE или FALSE, а не строку!

описание функции [mysql_query](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql_query)